# How do I jump/skip from line of codes/specific line of codes

Tags: excel, vba

When my generate a value in my `REVENUE ACCOUNTS` section, it runs properly. While when I generate a value in my `STOCK ACCOUNTS` section, it ends up mashing with my `REVENUE ACCOUNTS` section. How do I skip my `REVENUE ACCOUNTS` section when I input value on my `STOCK ACCOUNTS` section while jumping on my `GENERAL CODE`. Like `STOCK ACCOUNTS` to `GENERAL CODE`.

```
Sub ValidateCode2()
Dim igc As String, rev As String, cog As String, dis As String, brandlist As String, prodlist As String
Dim codres As String, revres As String, cogres As String, disres As String
Dim brandresult As String, prodresult As String
Dim i As Long
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook

sto = wb.Worksheets("Item Groups form").Range("C26").Value
cod = wb.Worksheets("Item Groups form").Range("C18").Value
rev = wb.Worksheets("Item Groups form").Range("C22").Value
dis = wb.Worksheets("Item Groups form").Range("F23").Value
cog = wb.Worksheets("Item Groups form").Range("F22").Value
brandlist = wb.Worksheets("Item Groups form").Range("C19").Value
prodlist = wb.Worksheets("Item Groups form").Range("D19").Value


'''FINISHED GOODS
'STOCK ACCOUNTS
For i = 2 To 13
    If sto = wb.Worksheets("Validation").Range("B" & i).Value Then 
        codres = wb.Worksheets("Validation").Range("D" & i).Value
        revres = wb.Worksheets("Validation").Range("E" & i).Value
        cogres = wb.Worksheets("Validation").Range("F" & i).Value
        disres = wb.Worksheets("Validation").Range("G" & i).Value
Next

'REVENUE ACCOUNTS
For i = 2 To 13
    If rev = wb.Worksheets("Validation").Range("E" & i).Value Then 
        stores = wb.Worksheets("Validation").Range("B" & i).Value
        codres = wb.Worksheets("Validation").Range("D" & i).Value
        cogres = wb.Worksheets("Validation").Range("F" & i).Value
        disres = wb.Worksheets("Validation").Range("G" & i).Value
Next

'''GENERAL CODE
'Brand
For i = 2 To 5000
    If brandlist = wb.Worksheets("Validation").Range("P" & i).Value Then
        brandresult = wb.Worksheets("Validation").Range("Q" & i).Value
Next

'Product
For i = 2 To 5000
    If prodlist = wb.Worksheets("Validation").Range("U" & i).Value Then
        prodresult = wb.Worksheets("Validation").Range("V" & i).Value
Next

wb.Worksheets("Item Groups form").Range("C18").Value = codres + prodresult + brandresult
wb.Worksheets("Item Groups form").Range("C22").Value = revres
wb.Worksheets("Item Groups form").Range("F22").Value = cogres
wb.Worksheets("Item Groups form").Range("F23").Value = disres
wb.Worksheets("Item Groups form").Range("C26").Value = stores

End Sub
```

Comment: One note: you don't need all those loops if each loop has the same condition. Can you add some sample data and explain what you're actually trying to do? There may be an easier way.

Comment: Use a `GoTo` statement

Answer (score 1):

Hi what you're looking to use is a `GoTo` function within an `IF` statement. I tucked it in at the end of the first block of the `FOR` loop, but it sounds like you want it based on a condition, but you can see how the `GoTo` function works, so you can adjust it accordingly.

I also changed your for loops to eliminate redundancies.

```
Sub ValidateCode2()
Dim igc As String, rev As String, cog As String, dis As String, brandlist As String, prodlist As String
Dim codres As String, revres As String, cogres As String, disres As String
Dim brandresult As String, prodresult As String
Dim i As Long
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook

sto = wb.Worksheets("Item Groups form").Range("C26").Value
cod = wb.Worksheets("Item Groups form").Range("C18").Value
rev = wb.Worksheets("Item Groups form").Range("C22").Value
dis = wb.Worksheets("Item Groups form").Range("F23").Value
cog = wb.Worksheets("Item Groups form").Range("F22").Value
brandlist = wb.Worksheets("Item Groups form").Range("C19").Value
prodlist = wb.Worksheets("Item Groups form").Range("D19").Value


'''FINISHED GOODS
'STOCK ACCOUNTS
For i = 2 To 13
    If sto = wb.Worksheets("Validation").Range("B" & i).Value Then 
        codres = wb.Worksheets("Validation").Range("D" & i).Value
        revres = wb.Worksheets("Validation").Range("E" & i).Value
        cogres = wb.Worksheets("Validation").Range("F" & i).Value
        disres = wb.Worksheets("Validation").Range("G" & i).Value
    Else:
        GoTo RevenueAccounts 'You can make this part another if statement to fit your conditions.
Next

RevenueAccounts:
For i = 2 To 13
    If rev = wb.Worksheets("Validation").Range("E" & i).Value Then 
        stores = wb.Worksheets("Validation").Range("B" & i).Value
        codres = wb.Worksheets("Validation").Range("D" & i).Value
        cogres = wb.Worksheets("Validation").Range("F" & i).Value
        disres = wb.Worksheets("Validation").Range("G" & i).Value
Next

'''GENERAL CODE
'Brand
For i = 2 To 5000
    If brandlist = wb.Worksheets("Validation").Range("P" & i).Value Then
        brandresult = wb.Worksheets("Validation").Range("Q" & i).Value
Next

'Product
For i = 2 To 5000
    If prodlist = wb.Worksheets("Validation").Range("U" & i).Value Then
        prodresult = wb.Worksheets("Validation").Range("V" & i).Value
Next

wb.Worksheets("Item Groups form").Range("C18").Value = codres + prodresult + brandresult
wb.Worksheets("Item Groups form").Range("C22").Value = revres
wb.Worksheets("Item Groups form").Range("F22").Value = cogres
wb.Worksheets("Item Groups form").Range("F23").Value = disres
wb.Worksheets("Item Groups form").Range("C26").Value = stores

End Sub
```